# How to use Steeping thread group with runtime controller

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use a steeping thread group with a runtime controller

Script flow

---

login 400 times
Business Flow -Runtime controller for  execution Transaction for the time period like 1 hour
logout 400 times

---

Now Test scenario
All Vuser 1 every 05 second
duration 1 hour
Stop Vuser 1 every 5 second

Steeping thread group I have given a 1-hour duration and in runtime controller also I have given an hour  duration

Issue:
My test run for 1 hour but logout is not happening.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping Thread Group doesn't know anything about presence of Runtime Controller(s) inside it, when 1 hour ends it tells threads to stop no matter whether they executed "logout" or not.

Personally I would rather:

1. Configure the Stepping Thread Group to perform the workload pattern:

   [image]
2. Put "Login" and "Logout" under [Once Only Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
3. Put the "Business Flow" under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) with the following condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long) < (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long) + 2000000 + 3600000,)}
   ```

   So it will execute the "Business Flow" for ramp-up period plus 1 hour and then proceed further

Test plan outline:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dmitri I tried the same way but still  not working for  me test stopped after the time duration we have provided in the while controller but still not able to  hit the last logout request

Comment: Your test stops when thread group stops

Comment: Test stopped after 1.5 hours (3600 min +2000) ramp-up time but didn't execute the logout request. how to handle that?

Comment: Test stops when thread group stops. You need to configure the While Controller to run shorter than the thread group. Alternatively you can put "login" into [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) and "logout" into [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) and pass the cookies via [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm)

Comment: I tried with less time (like 1 hour in the normal thread and 30 min in while controller )but ramp down is not working for example ramp up time is 5 users in 10 min and I have given ramp down 10 users in 10 mins but ram down is not happening in the required time(Ramp down is happening 5 users 10 min ).Is this the correct behaviour of JMeter in my scenario?